# No later version than .NET Core 2.1 available in Visual Studio 2019 Community

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I'm running Visiual Studio 2019 Community 16.9.4 and I can't install any .NET (Core) version later than 2.1, as you can see in the following screenshot under Installation details. [image]

Why can't I install for instance .NET 5, or .NET Core 3.1 (LTS)?

Comment: Check tab `Individual components`, you can find there `.Net Core 3.1 (LTS)` and `.Net 5`

Comment: @Genusatplay, no I can't. See my new screenshot.

Comment: Tab `Individual components` on top of screen? You can't open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab `Individual components` on top of the screen

[Install Visual Studio guide (Step 5)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-5---choose-individual-components-optional)